# VBA - Way to loop through sheets and change print settings without activating sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I sort of have two issues, but the one that I absolutely cannot find a straight answer to is can I loop through worksheets and apply Print SETTINGS to certain ones without activating them? It seems that activating sheets bogs down the time to run code and is frowned upon, but I can't find a way around it for print settings. (I know I shouldn't be "selecting" either, which I also do in this code).

My second issue is my IF THEN statement below is not excluding the three sheets listed ("LAS Report", "Criteria", and "Legend") when I run this. What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim wsh As Worksheet
For i = 1 To Application.Sheets.Count
Sheets(i).Activate
If wsh.Name <> "LAS Report" And wsh.Name <> "Criteria" And wsh.Name <> "Legend" Then
    With ActiveSheet
    .PageSetup.LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .PageSetup.RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .PageSetup.TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .PageSetup.BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .PageSetup.HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .PageSetup.FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
    .PageSetup.ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    .PageSetup.AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
    .PageSetup.Zoom = False
    .PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
    .PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False
    .PageSetup.PrintGridlines = True
    .PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
    .PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&A &D PAGE &P of &N"
    .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 25
    .Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 50
    .Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 19
    .Columns("N:N").ColumnWidth = 5
    .Columns("O:O").ColumnWidth = 7
    .Columns("Q:Q").ColumnWidth = 11
    .Columns("E:E").Hidden = True
    .Columns("I:J").Hidden = True
    .Columns("Q:Q").Hidden = True
    .Cells.EntireColumn.WrapText = True
    .Columns("A:A").Select
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
        .TintAndShade = 0.6
    End With
End If
    Range("A1").Select
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with how it's written. For instance, you never set `wsh` to be anything so the long `If` statement is moot. Try this at the beginning instead:

```vb
Dim i As Integer
Dim wsh As Worksheet
For i = 1 To Application.Sheets.Count
    Set wsh = Sheets(i)
    If wsh.Name <> "LAS Report" And wsh.Name <> "Criteria" And wsh.Name <> "Legend" Then
        With wsh
            ...
```

and this near the end:

```vb
            ...
            .Columns("Q:Q").Hidden = True
            .Cells.EntireColumn.WrapText = True
            With .Columns("A:A")
                .FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                .FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
                With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
                    .TintAndShade = 0.6
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End If
Next i
```

I have not tested this. The basic premise is to never activate or select anything. That means you don't reference it with `ActiveSheet` or `Selection`. This should also speed up how fast the code runs.

The only thing this doesn't do but the original does is select `A1` on each sheet because you don't do that without also activating the sheet.